# Prisma ORM not resolving to correct path in node modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, serverless, prisma

We have a project set up with Next.js and monorepo structure, using yarn workspaces. We have used Prisma as our ORM quite a while now. Last thursday the code suddenly broke. After researching it seems the `@prisma/client` import is not resolving to the proper node modules but rather is making a reference to another project:

`digital-assets/node_modules/@prisma/client/index"`

when it should be

`investments/node_modules/@prisma/client/index"`

Therefore it doesn't recognize the schemas related to that specific project. The error breaks the build.

This happened all of a sudden I tried to track down the commit but no luck, I reverted a lot of "possible" changes that could be related but none worked.

The error:

[image: Error prisma]

I don't know what to do, any Ideas I would be highly grateful. Thanks

Comment: Could you try explicitly specifying the output where the PrismaClient should be generated? And then import PrismaClient from that path: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/generating-prisma-client#using-a-custom-output-path